# QSciScintilla Background Color

Tags: c++, qt, qscintilla

I'm trying to change the color of the entire QSciScintilla editor widget. I've tried using the function

```
QSciScintilla::setPaper(const QColor &c)
```

but that seems to change only the color behind the text (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUz3A.png)). How can I change the background color of the ENTIRE box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love to know this too. QScintilla gives me endless grief.

Comment: @beta I know the feeling. Documentation is very scarce, until now. You can find lots of beginner-friendly docs on this site: https://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `setPaper` on the `QsciScintilla` widget will have no effect if a lexer has been set.

Try using the `setDefaultPaper` function of the current lexer.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually calling `setPaper` on the current lexer. `setDefaultPaper` did the trick. Thanks!